# React: Issues with Conditional Rendering

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In my React-App, i use the Firebase SDK. If a user wants to reset his password, he will be redirected to a page within my app. If the code is valid, the component `<PWResetConfirmForm />` should be rended. If the code is invalid, the component `<PWResetOutdatedForm />` is to be rendered.

My Page Component looks like this:

```js
class PWResetConfirmPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.verfiyResetPassword = this.verfiyResetPassword.bind(this);
    }

    verfiyResetPassword() {
        const params = (new URL(`http://dummy.com${this.props.location.search}`)).searchParams;
        const code = params.get("oobCode")

        auth.doVerfiyPasswordReset(code)
            .then(function () {
                return (
                    <div className="HomePage-Main">
                        <TopBar></TopBar>
                        <PWResetConfirmForm></PWResetConfirmForm>
                    </div>
                );
            })
            .catch(function () {
                return (
                    <div className="HomePage-Main">
                        <TopBar></TopBar>
                        <PWResetOutdatedForm></PWResetOutdatedForm>
                    </div>
                );
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.verfiyResetPassword()}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default PWResetConfirmPage
```

When i try to run, i get a blank page and not error. 
Where is my issue and how can i fix that?
Thank you very much for your help and for your time

Comment: Remember that browser have developer tools that let you inspect internals and see requests and responses.

Comment: @jdv thanks for your answer, but with installing React DEV Tools, i can't find anything, that looks like an error... do you have another idea for the cause? Is my function "verfiyResetPassword" correct? Can this function return something?

Comment: `verfiyResetPassword()` is probably not correct, you can't return JSX within a promise that way. At a basic level you'd be better off setting a boolean state property within the then/catch and rendering conditionally based on that property.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks for your answer... i am a React Beginner, could you show me, how can i do that with my file? Many Thanks

Comment: Sure, but when exactly do you execute `verfiyResetPassword()` in this component? Is it when the component loads? Is it when some button is clicked? How is it triggered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to return JSX from within `then()`/`catch()` of `auth.doVerfiyPasswordReset()` like that. You can instead approach this by taking advantage of React.Component lifecycle method [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and using `setState()` to manipulate state properties for conditional rendering. I've added state properties to the component, one to track whether loading (API call has completed) and one to track whether the call was a success (then) or failure (catch). These properties are used to conditionally generate JSX content for rendering. This is assuming that `verfiyResetPassword()` is intended to run when the component is first mounted, instead of every time `render()` is called:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); 
    this.state = {
      isResetVerified: null,
      loading: true
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.verfiyResetPassword();
  }

  verfiyResetPassword() {
    const params = (new URL(`http://dummy.com${this.props.location.search}`)).searchParams;
    const code = params.get("oobCode")

    auth.doVerfiyPasswordReset('foobar')
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isResetVerified: true,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isResetVerified: false,
          loading: false
        });
      })
  }

  getContent() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      );
    } else {
      if (this.state.isResetVerified) {
        return (
          <div className="HomePage-Main">
            <TopBar></TopBar>
            <PWResetConfirmForm></PWResetConfirmForm>
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <div className="HomePage-Main">
            <TopBar></TopBar>
            <PWResetOutdatedForm></PWResetOutdatedForm>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

Here is a basic [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7ctu5u) in action.

Also, in the constructor `this.verfiyResetPassword = this.verfiyResetPassword.bind(this);` would only be needed if `verfiyResetPassword()` is executed by a DOM event such as button `onClick` or similar.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I could still fix the error myself ;)

Answer (score 0):

I could still fix the error myself:

```js
class PWResetConfirmPage extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isValid: false,
            code: "",
        };
        this.verfiyResetPassword = this.verfiyResetPassword.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const params = (new URL(`http://dummy.com${this.props.location.search}`)).searchParams;
        const code = params.get("oobCode")
        this.setState({code:code})
        auth.doVerfiyPasswordReset(code)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isValid: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          isValid: false,
        });
      })
  }


    verfiyResetPassword() {
        if (this.state.isValid) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TopBar></TopBar>
                    <PWResetConfirmForm code={this.state.code}></PWResetConfirmForm>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div>
                    <TopBar></TopBar>
                    <PWResetOutdatedForm></PWResetOutdatedForm>
                </div>
            );
        }

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="HomePage-Main">
                {this.verfiyResetPassword()}
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default PWResetConfirmPage
```